# Magento custom url added with current page url

Tags: magento-1.8, url, redirect, 404-page

I am printing my custom URL's in footer which I am getting from database, Some thing like this
Assume this contains www.google.com link.

```
 <li><a href="<?php echo $links['link_url']?>"><?php echo $links['title'] ?></a></li>
```

When I click on this link at footer it rediecting with my current page url
**www.mydomainname.com/www.google.com**

How can I avoid attaching my current domain name to it?
It should be redirect to "www.google.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are viewing is the default behaviour `<a />` HTML tag. if the parameter specified in the `href` section is a relative term, then browser will append that parameter to the current url, while clicking on that link.

Here the parameter is `www.google.com`. For browser, it is a relative term and hence it is appending it to the current URL. Hence url will turn into `[your_current_url]/www.google.com`.

The solution is use the absolute url instead of relative term. ie use `http:://www.google.com`. ie your link should look like this.

```
<li><a href="http:://<?php echo $links['link_url']?>">
    <?php echo $links['title'] ?>
</a></li>
```

or simply

```
<li><a href="//<?php echo $links['link_url']?>">
     <?php echo $links['title'] ?>
</a></li>
```

That will do the trick.